# Deserialize json to object using mono touch for iPhone

Tags: serialization, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Is it possible to deserialize a JSON string to an object without using the DataContractJsonSerializer in System.ServiceModel.Web? I have the following code but I need a payed license to use it...

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(iar);
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));

Result result = (Result)ser.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using RestSharp to consume my Web.API service that sends data via JSON. However, I'm using JSON.NET to deserialize it.

```cs
_client.ExecuteAsync (request, (response) => {

    List<Account> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(response.Content);
```

This works just fine for me and JSON.NET is free, very quick, and kind of the de facto JSON serialization library for .NET.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work but I still get this cheesy license error http://cl.ly/NKPL ...

Comment: FYI: System.Runtime.Serialization will be allowed for Starter Edition in an upcoming Xamarin Studio / Xamarin.iOS update next week.